# Function `wildcard` doesn't see $@

Tags: makefile

I have the following `Makefile`:

```sh
.PHONY: all clean run
INC_DIR = include
SRC_DIR = src

KERNEL_NAME = mykernel
AS = as
ASPARAMS = --32
CXX = g++
CXXPARAMS = -m32 -ffreestanding -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -I$(INC_DIR)
#CXXPARAMS = -m32 -fno-use-cxa-atexit -nostdlib -fno-builtin -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -fno-leading-underscore -I$(INC_DIR)
LDPARAMS = -melf_i386
BUILD_DIR = build
ISO_DIR = $(BUILD_DIR)/iso
ISO_BOOT = $(ISO_DIR)/boot
GRUB_CONFIG = $(ISO_BOOT)/grub/grub.cfg

SRC = $(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)/*.cpp)
SRC += $(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)/**/*.cpp)
SRC +=  $(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)/*.s)
OBJS = $(SRC:=.o)
OBJS := $(addprefix $(BUILD_DIR)/, $(OBJS))
.SECONDARY: $(OBJS)

all: $(KERNEL_NAME).iso

run: $(KERNEL_NAME).iso
    qemu-system-i386 -cdrom $<

$(KERNEL_NAME).iso: $(GRUB_CONFIG) $(ISO_BOOT)/$(KERNEL_NAME).bin 
    grub-mkrescue -o $@ $(ISO_DIR)

$(ISO_BOOT)/$(KERNEL_NAME).bin: $(SRC_DIR)/linker.ld $(OBJS)
    ld $(LDPARAMS) -T $^ -o $@ -nostdlib

$(GRUB_CONFIG):
    mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    echo 'set timeout=0'                           > $(GRUB_CONFIG)
    echo 'set default=0'                           >> $(GRUB_CONFIG)
    echo ''                                        >> $(GRUB_CONFIG)
    echo 'menuentry "$(KERNEL_NAME) OS" {'         >> $(GRUB_CONFIG)
    echo '  multiboot2 /boot/$(KERNEL_NAME).bin'   >> $(GRUB_CONFIG)
    echo '  boot'                                  >> $(GRUB_CONFIG)
    echo '}'                                       >> $(GRUB_CONFIG)
    
$(BUILD_DIR)/%.cpp.o: %.cpp
    echo $(dir $@)
    echo $(wildcard (dir $@))

#ifeq ($(wildcard (dir $@)),)
# echo "mkdir -p $(dir $@)" ; 
# $(CXX) $(CXXPARAMS) $< -c -o $@
#endif

$(BUILD_DIR)/%.s.o: %.s
    @if [ ! -d $(dir $@) ]; then \
        echo "mkdir -p $(dir $@)" ; \
        mkdir -p $(dir $@) ; \
    fi
    $(AS) $(ASPARAMS) $< -o $@
    
clean:
    rm -rf $(KERNEL_NAME).iso $(BUILD_DIR)
```

Why do I get the output with empty `echo` by running `make`? The directory `build/src` exists.

```
echo build/src/
build/src/
echo 

echo build/src/
build/src/
echo 

echo build/src/
build/src/
echo 

echo build/src/
build/src/
echo 

echo build/src/
build/src/
echo 

echo build/src/
build/src/
echo 

echo build/src/gui/
build/src/gui/
echo 

echo build/src/gui/
build/src/gui/
echo 

ld -melf_i386 -T src/linker.ld build/src/Keyboard.cpp.o build/src/VGArray.cpp.o build/src/mykernel.cpp.o build/src/TextCursor.cpp.o build/src/VideoContext.cpp.o build/src/GDTable.cpp.o build/src/gui/DrawContext.cpp.o build/src/gui/Window.cpp.o build/src/loader.s.o -o build/iso/boot/mykernel.bin -nostdlib
ld: cannot find build/src/Keyboard.cpp.o: No such file or directory
ld: cannot find build/src/VGArray.cpp.o: No such file or directory
ld: cannot find build/src/mykernel.cpp.o: No such file or directory
ld: cannot find build/src/TextCursor.cpp.o: No such file or directory
ld: cannot find build/src/VideoContext.cpp.o: No such file or directory
ld: cannot find build/src/GDTable.cpp.o: No such file or directory
ld: cannot find build/src/gui/DrawContext.cpp.o: No such file or directory
ld: cannot find build/src/gui/Window.cpp.o: No such file or directory
Makefile:33: recipe for target 'build/iso/boot/mykernel.bin' failed
make: *** [build/iso/boot/mykernel.bin] Error 1
```

I tried to make a minimal example, but it works right when `build` directory exists.

```
.PHONY: all clean

CXX = g++
OPTS =  -Wall -Wextra
BUILD_DIR = build
APP = $(BUILD_DIR)/main
SRC_DIR = src
SRC = $(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)/*.cpp)

all: $(APP)

$(APP): $(APP).o
    
$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.cpp
    echo $(dir $@)
    echo $(wildcard $(dir $@))

clean:
    rm -rf $(BUILD_DIR) main *.o
```

Comment: The error message is literally that those .cpp.o files don't exist by the time you try to build build/iso/boot/mykernel.bin.  This usually missing a missing dependency.  What is $(OBJS) in the $(ISO_BOOT)/$(KERNEL_NAME).bin target?

Comment: Also, please provide a minimal example, and ideally a more specific question opposed to "Why do I get the output".

Comment: @AllanWind, I tried a minimal example, but it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `echo $(wildcard (dir $@))` by `echo $(wildcard $(dir $@))` and things should work as you expect.

Note: `SRC += $(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)/**/*.cpp)` will not recurse in subdirectories. If you believed it would, try:

```
SRC = $(shell find $(SRC_DIR) -type f -name '*.cpp')
SRC += $(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)/*.s)
```